# Decide if the polynomial $x^2-7$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q, \mathbb R, \mathbb C$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

I am trying to understand irreducibility of polynomials
and I am trying to solve the following question:

> Decide if the polynomial $x^2-7$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q, \mathbb R, \mathbb C$.

For Q

I tried to use the Eisenstein’s Criterion,
7/7, but 7^2/7 is not, I believe it's irreducible over Q

For R is reducible
(x-sqrt{7})(x+sqrt{7})

For C

Not sure

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Welcome to MSE ! Take a [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour). You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4413485/edit): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

The given polynomial is
$$x^2 - 7.$$

Since it is a two degree polynomial having no root in $\mathbb{Q}$, it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

But,
$$x^2-7=(x+\sqrt7)(x-\sqrt7)$$

So, it is reducible over $\mathbb{R}$.

Now, $\mathbb{R}$ is subset of $\mathbb{C}$ so
$\sqrt7$, $-\sqrt7$ are also elements in $\mathbb{C}$
$$\sqrt7=\sqrt7 + 0i$$
Hence, any polynomial which is reducible over $\mathbb{R}$ must be reducible over $\mathbb{C}$, too.

Comment: You need uniqueness of factorization here.

Answer (score 1):

The unique factorization is $x^2-7 = (x-\sqrt 7)(x+\sqrt 7)$.
By this uniqueness, $x^2-7$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$, but factors completely over $\Bbb R,\Bbb C$.

Answer (score -1):

Especially for $\mathbb{C}$ you should read about the fundamental theorem of Algebra which says that a polynomial of degree k has excactly k roots contained in $\mathbb{C}$. Thats why we say that the set of complex numbers is algebraic closed.

Comment: Why the OP needs to know that $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed in order to conclude that $x^2-7$ is reducible over $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Because all roots of every polynomial are included in $\mathbb{C}$ so each polynomial can be written in the form $(x-r_1)(x-r_2)\cdots(x-r_n)$ and so the polynomial is redhcible over $\mathbb{C}$. Of course its much simpler if you just factorise the polynomial and see that its reducible in reals so also in complexes, but the fundamental Algebra theorem is something really important for someone to know.